# Дубликат of вопроса

Tags: дефект, локализация, дубликаты

Заметил на [версиях вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/7097/revisions) ошибку локализации

> Сообщение закрыто по причине «дубликат» участником Nicolas Chabanovsky♦ of

И там дальше ссылка на вопрос.

Франгмент "of" надо бы как-то перевести, к примеру, "вопроса" или ещё как-то.

Comment: и так сойдет :-D